# Number Theory - Powers of (number) modulo (number)

Tags: number-theory

Why does 3^n modulo 17 (n=0, 1, 2 ...) result in all numbers between 1 and 16 whereas 3^n modulo 26 (n=0, 1, 2 ...) only result in 1, 3, & 9?
3^0 mod 17 = 1
3^1 mod 17 = 3
3^2 mod 17 = 9
3^3 mod 17 = 10
...
3^15 mod 17 = 6
3^n mod 17 with n = 0 -> 15 will have different results, and combined result in all numbers between 1 and 16.
However,
3^0 mod 26
3^1 mod 26
3^2 mod 26
...
3^25 mod 26
only results in 1, 3, & 9.

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Why on earth should the order of $3 \pmod {17}$ have anything to do with the order of $3\pmod {26}$?

Comment: Why does the result of 3^n (mod 17) result in all numbers between 0 and 16, whereas 3 (mod 26) only result in 1, 3, & 9?

Comment: Simply repeating the same words as in your post doesn't clarify your question.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about [primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

Comment: In a sense you've just uncovered orbits of group elements

Answer (score 1):

The groups of units (= invertible elements) of $\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z$ and of $\mathbf Z/26\mathbf Z$ are both cyclic, of orders $16$ and $12$ respectively.

However, this does not mean that *any* element $\ne 1$ is a generator, even if the ring is a field: in $\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z$, $2$ has order $8$, $4$ has order $4$.